# Making a custom keyboard with random letters on android app

Tags: android

Can someone please explain how apps like "Guess the emoji" and "4 pics 1 word" make the custom keyboard with random letters?
also, the blank white squares above it, what are they? buttons? EditText?

please explain how to make something like that properly,

Comment: Please, add more detail. We can't imagine what you are saying.

Comment: I mentioned two apps, please search them on google images to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Those custom keyboard is not provided by android studio, you have to create your own image, create an image one by one using editing software like photoshop, you have to create an image from A-Z then copy and paste that images to drawable folder in your android studio.

2nd the blank white squares above - it is not an EditText it is also an ImageView where those letters A-Z are being placed when pressing the letters.

I have created an app from Google Playstore called crazyword (Word game app) almost similar to "4 pics 1 word" but the concept is different

[Download crazyword here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=crazyword.com)

Image here
[image]